# Is there negative side effects if a promise never settles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

A common pattern I apply when writing unit tests, is to create a promise that never settles.

This allows me to setup the system in a loading state, and I can verify correct behavior while loading.

```
it("Return state 'LOADING'", () => {
    sinon.stub(api, 'findMySessions').returns(new Promise(r => {}));
    // loadMySessions is an async function, but I don't await it.
    loadMySessions(); 
    // Now the state of my system reflects the state it's in while waiting for a response
    expect(getState()).to.equal("LOADING");
});

afterEach(() => { sinon.reset() });
```

If the promise behaved like any other normal object, it should eventually be garbage collected. I create the instance and pass to sinon, which is asked to reset after each test. Nothing should keep a reference to this promise object.

However, node.js (or whichever javascript engine is running) might give promises a special treatment, e.g. in order to deal with unhandled rejections, or other run-time issues.

So could this piece of code cause a leak, or is it safe?

Comment: *I assume that the promise object will eventually be garbage collected* - why would you assume that?

Comment: @JaromandaX - Why would you assume the opposite? :-)

Comment: When the test has completed running, I don't see that anything keeps a reference to the Promise object. It's just passed to `sinon`, which is asked to reset after the test

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I wouldn't assume either - I didn't notice the code though

Comment: `resolve` and `reject` hold both references to the promise. So if you loose reference to both of them (as you do) as well as to the promise itself, both the Promise and all it's then callbacks are viable for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

**Unless** not settling means something keeps a reference to the promise that it would otherwise release, no, never settling the promise isn't a problem. Promises are just objects,¹ and settled/unsettled is just object state.

---

¹ (*although native ones have some interaction with the JavaScript engine normal objects don't have, so the engine can intelligently report unhandled rejections fairly efficiently*)

Comment: I handled promise rejections can be implemented without native promises.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED - Not quite as effectively or efficiently. But yes, in most ways. Native promises have the advantage of being more directly plumbed in.

Comment: Honestly my experience is native implementations are often less efficient. There's a barrier bewteen C++ and JavaScript that makes it harder to efficiently deal with the native objects. Eventually the JS engine might incorporate those objects efficiently but it can take years. A good example are TypeArrays. They were slower than native arrays for 8-9 years because to JS they were basically a foreign object. They're still slower on some modern JS engines.

Comment: @gman - That boundary can be an issue, yes, but that's not relevant to what I'm calling out in the answer. I'm calling out the various ways JavaScript engines can detect that a promise rejection has gone unhandled, which is a non-trivial problem,  because of the integration btw native promises and the engine. It's not just a matter of "If the promise is rejected and there's no handler, report the problem." That naive approach results in false positives, for instance `Promise.reject().catch(...)`. This all a side issue, though, and I have to get back to work.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your answer, only with the comment. Native promises are not inherently more efficient. That was my only point.

Comment: @gman - But detecting unhandled rejections with them is, I'm fairly sure. That's *my* only point. :-)

Comment: "detecting" unhandled rejections makes no difference in native or JavaScript land. There is nothing in the native part surrounding this mechanism that cannot be done with JavaScript. Your original comment made no indication about the performance. That's what I was responding to.